# Select users based on their date joined and date left

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, datetime

I have the following table:

**Person**

```
UserID Name Date_Joined Date_Left 
1      Test  2018-08-10 NULL
2      Test2 2018-07-10 NULL
3      Test3 2018-07-10 2018-12-31
4      Test4 2018-08-10 2018-09-10
```

I want to check by only their join and/or left date if they are billable(=active) or not.

These are billable users:

1. User whose start month is at least one month before billdate
    with no date left
2. User whose start month is at least one month before billdate
    with date left month equal to the billdate or later than the
    billdate

Month of billing = **always the previous month.**

I use the following query:

```
DECLARE @billdate AS DATE = '2018-09-01';
SELECT * 
FROM person
WHERE CompanyID = 1205 AND (
    (
        date_joined <= EOMONTH(@billdate, -1)
    )
    OR
    (
        date_left >  EOMONTH(@billdate, -1) AND
        date_left <= EOMONTH(@billdate)
    )
)
```

My problems:

- User Test4 is still present in my table if I set the billdate to `2018-11-01`.
- User Test3 dissapears if i set billdate to `2019-01-01`

What is wrong with my query and how can I optimize this?

**Sample data:**

User list:

1 - Test  - 2018-08-10 - NULL

2 - Test2 - 2018-07-10 - NULL

3 - Test3 - 2018-07-10 - 2018-12-31

4 - Test4 - 2018-08-10 - 2018-09-10

For the bill period of the previous month  (= 8 / August) = `@billdate 2018-09-10`, these are the billable users:

Test2
Test3

However, when I change the bill period to 10 / october, these are the billable users:

Test
Test2
Test3

Comment: Can you implement `@billdate`in your sample data?

Comment: I'd like to make a general suggestion to you for next time you want to get help here: 1) show sample data which clearly explains your question and which covers ALL edge cases, and 2) don't leave tons of comments under everyone's answers.  If you find yourself doing this, blame yourself for not explaining your question well enough.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you very much for your advice, I will remind myself about this in the future

Comment: If you can [edit my demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6650ce9155d15f454c6954afa9800b69), add new data, and then tell me where my answer is still going wrong, I'm happy to try another update.

Comment: Your demo is perfect to my (psychedelically asked) question! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your logic correctly, a billable user is one whose start month is at least one month before the current month, and whose end month is less than or equal to the current month.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN @billdate >= DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(date_joined)) AND
              (@billdate <= DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(date_left)) OR date_left IS NULL)
         THEN 'billable'
         ELSE 'not billable' END AS status
FROM person;
```

This billing logic appears to be consistent with customers getting the first month free, but being billable from the second up to the final month.

### Demo

Comment: No, a billable user can be the following: 1 - User whose start month is at least one month before billdate with no date left| 2 - User whose start month is at least one month before billdate with date left month equal to the billdate or later than the billdate

Comment: I changed it and added sample data

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your query won't work for users that joined last year and have no date_left

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in your, demo, when I change billdate to 2019-01-01 , the person Test3 is not billable. Or is this because you don't check to check the previous month?

Comment: So, to be clear, are you now saying that a customer gets billed for one month _after_ the month in which he left?

Comment: Yes but the billdate should check the `previous month` . This means that if the `billdate` is 2019-01-01 , it should check to december 2018

Comment: Yes because in Jan-2019, we check the billable people of Dec-2018

Comment: Yes!! but I failed to understand what you changed, I would have thought that you would do it by subtracting -1 month . Thank you very much and I'm sorry for the confusion(s), could you just edit the answer to incorporate it in my query? I would still need to use the `clausule` right?

Comment: Is it possible to incorperate this in my query without using `CASE`-statements? as I actually use this to retrieve the matched rows only without adding a test column

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have noticed one 'error' actually in your latest demo, it still sees that the users joined on the previous month of billing as billable (even even though they shouldn't). if the billdate is `2018-09-01` , the user that joined on `2018-08-30` should be marked as `non billable`

Answer (score 0):

use make flag comparing join month and year with bill month and year and create a flag for each user then use sub-query for filter

```
  select * from t
(
 select *,case when (month(date_joined)=month(billdate) 
   and  year(date_joined)=year(billdate)) then 'N' else 'Y' end as flag_billable
  from user
) as t where t.flag_billable='Y'
```

For your query

```
DECLARE @billdate AS DATE = '2018-09-01';
select * from 
(
    SELECT * ,case when (month(date_joined)=month(@billdate) 
           and  year(date_joined)=year(@billdate)) then 'N' else 'Y' end as  flag_billable
    FROM person
) t where t.flag_billable='Y'
```